# Firebase UI does not work for me (cannot download images) swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebaseui

I have 2 questions:

1. Where in the code do I put the profilePicture function?
2. what do I do, when the Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned?

Can you guys help me? As of now the code does not work for me.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class testProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pfp: UIImageView!

    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "profileImages")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        profilePicture()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func profilePicture(){

        pfp.layer.cornerRadius = pfp.frame.size.width / 2
        pfp.clipsToBounds = true

        let imageView: UIImageView = self.pfp

        let ref = pathReference.child(uid)

        ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
          if let error = error {
            print(error)
          } else {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            print("it worked")
          }
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: You may have tried lots of things but the import thing to try is to actually implement the code to download the file. There's a great example in the Getting Started Guide [Download files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files). Give that a try and let us know where you get stuck by updating the question. Also, be carefuly about how the path is defined - in the question it's currently *your_storage/profileImages/profileImages/uid* which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The problem is: The path that you described, actually is the path to the photo I need @Jay

Comment: Really? */profileImages/profileImages/*? As I mentioned in my above comment, there's no code in the question that actually downloads the file.

Comment: oh shoot! Haven't seen this, thank you!
I still have no idea (I am a noob) and I have updated the post. Would you mind to take a look? @Jay

Comment: That's better but since your controller has a pfp class var which is a UIImageView, you can just replace this `let image = UIImage(data: data!)` with `if let data = data { self.pfp.image = UIImage(data: data) }`. Other than that, what's not working? To help us help you, please do some further troubleshooting to isolate where the issue is, then include that in the question. You can start by adding breakpoints and stepping through the code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Its finally working! Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart. I spent days without an answer and you were the only one to help me! @Jay

Comment: Thanks again! You are very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controller has a imageView class var, pfp,

```
class testProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var pfp: UIImageView!
```

that can be addressed directly. So this code can be replaced

```
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

with this - noting we are safely unwrapping the optional data var

```
if let data = data { 
   self.pfp.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```